# Storing Variable Row/Column CSV Files In Database

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a large collection of CSV data that is created by an application which I would like to store in a database preferably SQL Server. This data can have any number of columns and any number of rows and storing each one as a separate table doesn't make much sense. It would also be great to be able tosearch on this data. What is the best way of putting this data into a database.

For example (and I am simplifying things greatly here), consider just 3 CSV files that might look like:

```
File 1:
aaa,bbb,ccc
ddd,eee,fff
ggg,hhh,iii

File 2:
jjj,kkk
lll,mmm

File 3:
nnn,ooo,ppp,qqq,rrr
sss,ttt,uuu,vvv,www
xxx,yyy,zzz,111,222
333,444,555,666,777
```

I might be over simplifying this but I can't post actual data due to strict NDA.

How would it be best to store this in a database? There will be thousands of files each of which could in theory by in different column widths and different number of rows.

**EDIT:
Could a Data Mart be used to achieve this and if so how? Any pointers?**

Comment: For each of these imported files, is there one id column, and might you consider that all other columns are properties for that object? In that case you might consider what's called a "property bag" table. However, use for that kind of "generic" table is very limited and can only be considered for some scenarios where constraints are clear. http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=25942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each file create a record in a 'csv file' table.

For each column-name create a record in a 'csv file header name' table with a corresponding column index.

For each csv row create a key value hashmap where 'key' is the 'column index' and 'value' is the 'row' data. Serialise this hashmap to an XML string and then store this XML in a 'csv file data' table XML column.

You can then use XPath to SELECT the XML row data JOINing the 'column index' columns to retrieve the original file column headers.

**EDIT:**

Tables

```
CSVFile
PK  FilePath
...
7   [\\server1\somedir\foo.csv]
9   [\\server1\dir\bar.csv]
...

CSVFileColumnHeader
PK  FileId  ColumnIndex ColumnName
...
980 7       5           [foo quant]
981 7       6           [foo size]
982 9       3           [bar depth]
..

CSVFileRowData
PK      FileId  RowIndex    RowDataAsXML
..  
1054    7       35          <ArrayOfSerialisableKeyValuePair>...<SerialisableKeyValuePair><Key>5</Key><Value>17</Value></SerialisableKeyValuePair><SerialisableKeyValuePair><Key>6</Key><Value>8cm</Value></SerialisableKeyValuePair>...</ArrayOfSerialisableKeyValuePair>
1055    7       36          <ArrayOfSerialisableKeyValuePair>...<SerialisableKeyValuePair><Key>5</Key><Value>8</Value></SerialisableKeyValuePair><SerialisableKeyValuePair><Key>6</Key><Value>35cm</Value></SerialisableKeyValuePair>...</ArrayOfSerialisableKeyValuePair>
1056    9       4           <ArrayOfSerialisableKeyValuePair>...<SerialisableKeyValuePair><Key>3</Key><Value>4 metres</Value></SerialisableKeyValuePair>...</ArrayOfSerialisableKeyValuePair>
...
```

And then an XPath query like this:

```
SELECT  
    CFR.FileId                                      'FileId'
    ,tab.col.value('./Key[1]', 'INT')               'ColumnIndex'
    ,CFR.RowIndex                                   'RowIndex'
    ,tab.col.value('./Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)')    'RowValue'
    ,CFC.ColumnName                                 'ColumnName'
FROM 
            CSVFileRowData  CFR
CROSS APPLY RowDataAsXML.nodes('//SerialisableKeyValuePair')tab(col)
INNER JOIN  CSVFileColumnHeader CFC ON tab.col.value('./Key[1]', 'INT') = CFC.ColumnIndex
```

Would return data in this format:

```
FileId  ColumnIndex RowIndex    RowValue        ColumnName
...
7       5           35          [17]            [foo quant]
7       6           35          [8cm]           [foo size]
..
```

Comment: Sounds interesting but I'm having trouble getting my head around what you are suggesting. Is there example that can be linked to? Preferably with a diagram.

Comment: Thanks. Looks very promising (other than I won't have a columnn name for any of the files).

Comment: Will I then be able to select this data into an ADO Recordset?

Comment: @Jonnster Yes, no problems using an ADO Recordset. Hope you get some good alternatives.