# Upload a csv file to a attribute-value model

Tags: django, csv, models, key-value

Recently I am dealing with a following problem:
I am trying to build an "archive" for storing and retrieving data from various sources, so the data will always have different number of columns and rows. I think that allowing the user to create new tables just to store those CSV files (each in separate files ) would a serious violation of web development guidelines and also difficult to achieve in Django. That's why I came up with idea of attribute-value format for storing the data, but I don't know how to implement it in django.

I want to build a form in Django Admin to allow user to upload a CSV file with N-columns  to a table that contains only two columns: 1)name of the column from csv file and 2) value for that column (more precisly: three value columns: one for integers, one for floats and one for storing strings. To do that I must of course "melt" the data from CSV file to a "long" format so the file:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
23 | 45.0 | 32
```

becomes:

```
key| val
col1| 23
col2 | 45.0
col3 | 32
```

And that I know how to do. However, i do not know if it is possible to process a file that is uploaded by the user to such a format and, later, how to retrive data in a simple, django-way. 
Do you know of any such extensions /widegts or how to approach the problem? Or how to google it even? I have done my research, however, I found only general approaches for dynamic models and I don't think that my case requires using them:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model
and here's dynamic model approach:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dynamo - however, I am not sure it's the right answer.

So my guess is that I do not understand django really that well, but I'd be grateful for some directions.

Comment: Take it piece by piece. Otherwise you won't know which pieces of the puzzle you are missing. what models did you define? Where is your form? Where is your template? What parts of django you do not understand? Did you try the official tutorial?

Comment: Yes I did, however what I want to do isn't covered there. I will edit the question for more clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need a dynamic model. And you should avoid EAV(Entity Attribute Value)
schemas. It's bad desing.

Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/) for how to process an uploaded file.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) for how to override the `save()` instance method. This
is probably what you'll need to do.

Also, keep in mind that what you call `melting` is called `serializing`. It is helpful
to know the right terms and definitions when searching for these topics.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for that, now I know what to google for! I was wondering about which term to use, I have stastistical background and it's common (at least in R) to use the term "melting". Also, I can't vote your answer up, because it's my first topic on SO, though I have been a user for few years now:)

Comment: @mhnatiuk It's ok about the voting. Thanks for the accept. Good luck solving your problem.

Comment: OK, after rethinking the problem: now I know that I can easily save the data the way I have described previously, but that raises yet another question, but from a different level: a design question which you ( @rantanplan) have explicitly stated previously. Is it a good idea at all to store csv data in the "long" format? To remind: the data itself is of different length in terms of rows and colums and also what I want to do with it later is to easily  subset the data ("select *** where some_condition_is_met") and even merge different datasets. Can you recommend an approach or lectures to read?

Comment: @mhnatiuk Length of rows does not matter. Length of columns though does. If you have really that dynamic range of length in columns, store these data in an hstore(dictionary like) datatype of postgres. It supports some type of queries that may or may not be enough for your case. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

Comment: @mhnatiuk Otherwise consider off-loading this data in a separate no sql backend like mongodb or hadoop. Depends on your size of data and the type of analysis you want to perform. Hadoop is for really large data sets.

Comment: I think that hadoop would be an overkill in this case: Institute that I work for collects data from school surveys. We will have around 100-200 dataframes of 7K-8K rows. It sums up to 700-800k rows and even with very wide tables they won't contain more than 3k columns. So roughly estimation shows that the overall size wouldn't exceed 5GB. Is this a case for considering MongoDb?

Comment: @mhnatiuk 3,000 columns? Wow, that's way too much for an RDBMS. Research a bit how mongodb would scale with that metrics. I think you probably need a map-reduce engine afterall. Search for all the db engines that support map-reduce operations. My experience with no-sql and map-reduce are limited to mongodb and couchdb. I doubt they are appropriate for your workload though. I'm not qualified to give you further advice on these matters, except that you need a map-reduce engine.

Comment: 3k: well, that's _the_ _extreme_ case: a survey with many, many items, but not too much rows. So the data itself isn't that big

Comment: @mhnatiuk See http://cassandra.apache.org/. It's a column-oriented database. It may suit you better.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a look, however: I don't think that our data is that huge. The only problem I have to solve is to come up with an idea how to store CSV files (with some metadata about it) in a database, as to allow merging and subseting the data faster than just by stroing csv on disk and loading it into the memory every time. So as you see, I am still at the "problem definition" level..

Comment: @mhnatiuk Did you check out postgres' `hstore`? Also you could always store it as a JSON string. There are many 3rd party `JSONField`s out there for django. If you don't mind the slowness of serializing/deserializing the json to python dictionary and vice versa.

Comment: I do mind actually, I don't care about inserting time, however data retreival time on the user-side should be at least fair.. I gave hstore a look, but as far as I understood that I would have to store an entire column of data as key-value pairs, so I would end up with the following table for example: row: ( column_name, column_type, another_column_info, values = {'0': '1st value', '1':'2nd value', ... ,'n', '3rd value'}. Can you confirm this? I think that data retrieval would be vary slow for larger values (N=4000) of N. Maybe cassandra is a better choice, but I am not sure yet.

Comment: OK, I found one thread that is most accurately related to my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327737/storing-variable-row-column-csv-files-in-database . Can you somehow recommend to me whether this is a better approach than hstore ? Or is it exactly the case for using an hstore column type in place of column containing XML data?

Comment: @mhnatiuk The question and answer you linked seems highly convoluted to me. XPATH queries on xml inside an rdbms? Talk about the wrong tool for the job! About hstore: keep in mind that the values will always be converted to strings/text. That means you can only do `equals` or `contains` queries. You can't do "where key => 5" for example. If that's OK to you, hstore is a good solution. Otherwise try mongodb which is pretty simple to setup and if that won't work out, go for cassandra, which I have no experience but seems good for your use case.

Comment: I will give mongodb a look, I think that now I understand that it's necessary to use some kind of noSql solution. I must now understand how to create a mongodb data model for my data :) Thanks

Comment: Hey, just updating: MongoDB solution worked, I am currently testing whether it's performance on a single machine is acceptable, but it seems so. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mhnatiuk Hey you're welcome. Really glad it worked out for you!